# Breakdown code for concatenating CSV files I found from a previous question?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I had hundreds of CSV files to merge, and doing so manually would have taken weeks. As a result, I decided to learn Python. Unfortunately I didn't have time to learn enough to resolve my problem so I found a code here that would merge the CSV files and add the filename into a new column. My problem is solved, but now I actually want to understand what I did. Can someone breakdown what each line did? Many thanks.

```
import pandas as pd 
import glob 
import os

globbed_files = glob.glob("*.csv")  

data = []  
for csv in globbed_files:
    frame = pd.read_csv(csv)
    frame['filename'] = os.path.basename(csv)
    data.append(frame)


bigframe = pd.concat(data, ignore_index=True)
bigframe.to_csv("Pandas_output2.csv")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start by importing the libraries you need to use

```
import pandas as pd 
import glob 
import os
```

This line creates a list of path names to all files that meet the *.csv wildcard within the directory

```
globbed_files = glob.glob("*.csv")
```

You create an empty list called 'data' to put stuff into later

```
data = []
```

This loop is putting all of the data of each CSV file into the 'data' list.

```
for csv in globbed_files:
    frame = pd.read_csv(csv)
    frame['filename'] = os.path.basename(csv)
    data.append(frame)
```

For each csv that was found, this loop will read the csv file into a [dataframe](https://www.shanelynn.ie/using-pandas-dataframe-creating-editing-viewing-data-in-python/) (called 'frame'). Like a [dictionary](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp) it has 'keys' and 'values'. In this case, the 'key' is like the header information in the CSV file that describes the contents of the column, and the 'values' is a list of the data in that column.

The dataframe 'frame' has all of the csv file's data put into it with

```
frame = pd.read_csv(csv)
```

then another 'key' is added to the dataframe (called 'filename') that contains the name of the CSV file whose data was just captured. I don't know if this is required but it would likely be very helpful to query where data came from originally once it is all inside the big CSV file.

```
frame['filename'] = os.path.basename(csv)
```

Then this dataframe containing all of the data from the current CSV file is appended to the original list called 'data' that was defined before the loop. 'frame' then gets replaced again at the start of the next iteration in the loop

```
data.append(frame)
```

After the loop finishes, all of the data from all of the CSV files is contained in 'data' list. The next line has panda concatenate it back into a dataframe called 'bigframe'

```
bigframe = pd.concat(data, ignore_index=True)
```

Then 'bigframe' is exported back out as a CSV file

```
bigframe.to_csv("Pandas_output2.csv")
```